# Get the last value in a node in Firebase database Ionic 3

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

[image: Firebase_database]

I have a database in firebase like the image. I want to get data from the last value in a node in firebase. How i can do it with ionic 3. Thank alot.

Comment: Have a look at https://kieldev.wordpress.com/2017/04/28/firebase-real-time-database-using-angular-4-ionic-3/

Comment: Hi bro thanks for answer me. In this link, it return a list with all values in the node. I want only the last value node.

Comment: Have you tried 
`databaseReference.child("tokens").orderByKey().limitToLast(1);`

Comment: How i can write it in typescript, i'm new in ionic and firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public getLastToken(): FirebaseListObservable<any[]>{
  return this._af.database.list('/tokens',{
      query:{
          limitToLast:1
      }
  });
}
```

This should work if you follow the tutorial, https://kieldev.wordpress.com/2017/04/28/firebase-real-time-database-using-angular-4-ionic-3/